# filtering data frames columns based on vector in a loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 467 columns. When I want to select specific columns

```
input <- c("bread", "milk")
for (i in 1:length(input)){
    flow <- df[input[i]]}
```

It return only the "milk" column. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Why not just `flow <- df[, c("bread", "milk")]`? Or is there more to that `for` loop?

Comment: So I want to build a dataframe, but it joins columns from dataframe “flow” 2 times

`for (i in 1:length(input)){
    flow <- data_cropped_f[input[i]]
    menu <- cbind(menu, flow)  
    menu$score <- menu$score+ as.numeric(menu[,input[i]])
  }`

Comment: You're *repeatedly* `cbind`ing `menu` in your `for` loop. Is that *really* what you want to do?

Comment: I just want to join 2 dataframes based on the `input`. Should I not write it in a loop?

Comment: Joining two dataframes is best done with `merge` (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right).

Comment: it also gives the following error `menu$score <- as.numeric(menu$score)+ as.numeric(menu[,input])
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`